# Best way to copy bits in terms of performance, in C#

Tags: c#, performance, bit-manipulation, arrays

What's the fastest way to copy `bit`s from an `Int` to a `byte array`, in **C#**?

I have a couple of `int`s and I need to copy (sometimes all and somtimes some of) the `bit`s serially into a `byte[]`...

I need the process to be as efficient as possible (e.g. avoid creating new `byte array` in the process as I understand the `BitConverter` does etc).

Comment: What's the problem with creating a new byte array?  Have you measured and verified that this is a significant performance problem or are you solving a problem that may not exist?  Have you tried more that one method yet?  What are the results?

Comment: @DStanley Especially considering we're talking about copying bits, which would suggest a new byte array in the first place...

Comment: You can always get the component bytes "by hand": `var b0=val&0xff; var b1=(val>>8)&0xff; var b2=(val>>16)&0xff; var b3=(val>>24)&0xff;` and do what you want with them.

Answer (score 3):

One way to avoid creating new `byte[]` array on each call is to create a `BinaryWriter` on top of a `MemoryStream`, write your integers into it, and then harvest all the results at once by accessing `MemoryStream`'s buffer:

```
var buf = new byte[400];
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buf))
using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms)) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 100 ; i++) {
        bw.Write(2*i+3);
    }
}
// At this point buf contains the bytes of 100 ints
```

Comment: Due to the interface of a stream, it would need to create at least one byte array as a buffer

Comment: @MagikM18 Could you be more specific about this? I am passing the buffer `buf` to `MemoryStream`, and I can keep re-using the same stream or the same buffer.

Comment: This is the function that it will use to write to the stream: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write(v=vs.110).aspx because this takes the data as a byte array, there must be another array that is created.

Comment: @MagikM18 I see what you mean. In the reference implementation `BinaryWriter` creates this buffer of size 16 once, and keeps reusing it.  See field called `_buffer` [in the source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/BinaryWriter@cs/1305376/BinaryWriter@cs).

Comment: Fair enough, I just saw that too